# node.js executables not working on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm attempting to make package run via executable, but it's not executing on windows. Not sure what's wrong, and helpdocs haven't supplied much help.

Whenever I try to run it with the below snippet, I get a "Windows Script Host" error GUI.

```
"bin": {
    "kaga": "bin/index.js"
}
```

Whenever I use this, I get a terminal error (included below)

```
"bin": {
    "kaga": "./bin/"
}
```

```
"C:\Users\Kagetane\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\kaga\bin"
'"C:\Users\Kagetane\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\kaga\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, never mind, I got it. All I needed was a shebang line in bin/index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```